# Alljoyn sample app resources

Tags: java, android, alljoyn

After going through several documents on the Allseen website, I found outdated git hub links. There were download links to download sdks for android and linux. But is there a download available for the onboarding app for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the Dashboard Android app to onboard Alljoyn devices. Git clone the repo to get the sources:
`git clone https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/contributed_applications/dashboard.git`

or download the apk from the CDN at:
http://mirrors.kernel.org/allseenalliance/alljoyn/15.04/Dashboard_01_01_5.apk

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! That is helpful.